# use fiddler to capture html input value on the request

Tags: c#, fiddler

I use fiddler to inject fields into the response using this:

```
var oRegEx1 = /(<\/body>)/gi;
oBody = oBody.replace(oRegEx1, "<input type='text' id='txt1' />$1");
```

I then append large value to that field.

What I want to do is that during the OnBeforeRequest fiddler capture that field, store its current value into a string variable and populate the field again in the response.

I do this to store large values that cookie won't allow me.

How to implement it? Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Whether it's a "good approach" or not entirely depends on what higher-level goal you're trying to achieve. In terms of the implementation, you haven't really provided enough detail on your goal. You can read the request body inside either `OnBeforeRequest` or `OnBeforeResponse` and you can read/modify the response body inside `OnBeforeResponse`.

Comment: The goal is similar to this example:
I have 1000 of pages of potential customers from another site. I want to construct their urls that only differentiate in the id of each customer. Fiddler will load each page and inject a new filed (txt1) and jquery that will trigger, grab the id i want, append it to the existing value in a textbox and initiate the call to the next page.
so, how do I make fiddler reference the value of the text box during request so in response phase, it inject the stored value from before into the textbox that will get created again, so continually preserving the value. thx

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to build a crawler with a browser as the engine. Why not issue the request directly from Fiddler itself, building up the URL and request in C# or script code?